# typescript new line character in string is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using a directive to show a tooltip text:

```
<i class="fas fa-info-circle" [nz-tooltip]='infoBulleContent'  nzTooltipPlacement='topRight'></i>
```

in ts code, `this.infoBulleContent = 'Some text \n some text';` 
but the \n is not working, i used also the br tag, same result!

any help please

Answer (score 3):

This won't work, alas. As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/7fac8eb5b1e1c17dbfbf940827f1ca53dae8d5e4/components/tooltip/tooltip.ts#L119) of this tooltip component, the title that you give is not parsed but directly included as a string in the template.

Having said that, what you probably want here is to pass a `TemplateRef`, which allows you to include multiple lines, but also styling (which is preferable over using manual br-line breaks). E.g.

```html
    <!-- Element that should have a tooltip -->
    <button nz-tooltip [nzTooltipTitle]="titleTemplate">Test</button>

    <!-- Contents of tooltip -->
    <ng-template #titleTemplate>
      <p style="font-size: 25px">Your <br> tooltip</p>
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` does not cause a line break in html.
You'll need to use a `<br/>` or wrap your text in a block element.

```
this.Values += this.Id + ',' + this.status + '<br/>';
```

or

```
this.Values += '<div>' + this.Id + ',' + this.status + '</div>';
```